# How to add a fixed margin on the top of the page

Tags: html, css, fixed

At first I thought it would be a simple fix, then I started losing brain cells by the minute.

I am providing a [***CODEPEN HERE***](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjeyn/)

Basically, I have two elements on the top of the page and they must remain fixed, while the bottom of the page (the content) scrolls naturally, without ***underlapping the fixed elements***.

Any ideas?

The HTML

```
  <body >
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebarmenu">
            <ul class="sidebarmenu1">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="1.html">Info</a></li>
                <li><a href="11.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="2.php">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="3.php">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="4.php">Page 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="5.php">Page 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="6.php">Page 6</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
        <div class="banner" >
            <img style="" alt="logo text" src="http://www.garethjmsaunders.co.uk/blueprint/placeholders/gif/grid/span-11-rows-15.gif" />            
        </div>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent" >
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. <br><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.<br><br>

          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.<br><br>

          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.
            </div>
     </body>
```

The CSS

```
      body {background-color: black; width: 980px; margin: 0px auto;} 
      .wrapper {width: 100%; } /*this shows the element fixed positioning is working */
      .container {width:100%; margin:0 auto; padding: 0px 15px; background-color: black; overflow:hidden} 

      .banner {margin: 15px 0px 0px 500px; position:fixed; }
      .spacer{background-color:black; height:290px;}
      .mainContent { color:white; z-index:-1; margin-top:20px; width: 980px; overflow:hidden}

       /* sidebar */
       .sidebarmenu {float: left; background-color:Black; position:fixed; margin: 15px; }

       .sidebarmenu ul{margin: 0;padding: 0;list-style-type: none;font: bold 13px Verdana;width: 180px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}

       .sidebarmenu ul li a{display: block;overflow: auto;color: black;text-decoration: none;padding: 6px;border-bottom: 1px solid #778;border-right: 1px solid #778;} 

       .sidebarmenu ul li a:link, .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited, .sidebarmenu ul li a:active{ background-color: #c0c0c0;}

       .sidebarmenu ul li a:visited{color: white;}

       .sidebarmenu ul li a:hover{background-color: black;color:red;}
```

Comment: Please do post here; searchability and helpfullness to future readers are important aspects of the Q/A format here. And some people just won't click such links.

Comment: Why not consider putting the sidebar and the banner in the same parent element, whose position is set to fixed with a background colour defined? In that case, you can prevent the content of the page from appearing underneath the fixed elements, if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Terry, That sounds like something I want or probably already tried. Or maybe I messed up when I tried it, and then wrote it off. Let me check that again. That is the most logical behavior

Comment: Of course, it would not work if you have a dynamic background (like an image, a gradient and the likes). If that is the case, you might want to explore using CSS mask, but that is going to be at the cost of users on older browsers...

Comment: @Terry Yeah, I was afraid of that. In fact I mentioned it in an answer to a comment below in this post. If I had to mask, I would but not my preferred method. Why does overflow-y:hidden keep popping in my head, yet it does nothing?

Comment: Overflow only works when the content of an element exceeds its boundaries. In your CodePen, the main text's containing element has its borders extend to the top of the screen, therefore it is not in fact overflowing at all, so setting an overflow property does nothing. Setting position other than relative or static will take the element in question out of the document flow.

Comment: @Terry You are right. However, as I feared, remember what you suggested that I told you I had tried, but didn't work? I missed a close <div> So that's why :palm to forehead: So, if you want to post it a real answer, I'll mark it for ya.

Comment: See my updated answer (attached fiddle, explained the edits I made) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trick to solving this problem is that instead of separately declaring fixed positions for sidebar and the banner, group them under a common parent element whose position is set to fixed. You can then give the parent element a background colour to allow it to mask any content that comes under it.

See your revised example ported over to a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/88Sf9/1/

The revised CSS rules are as follow:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
.container {
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
} 
.mainContent {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 290px;
  width: 980px;
}
```

Some notes:

- You don't need to declare a negative z-index for the `.mainContent`
- You can safely remove the `overflow: hidden;` declaration

I have also applied a top padding to your main container, so that the content will be padded away from the fixed elements at the top of the viewport when your scroll position along the y-axis is 0 (i.e. when you are at the top of the page).

However, the solution will not work if you are handling a container with dynamic background, e.g. images or gradients. For that case, you might want to look into using CSS masks, which suffers from lack of cross-browser support and standardization.

Answer (score 1):

Put a big black fixed box behind the two elements.

Comment: It did nothing. In fact, I actually never really took it off, run the codepen and look for the div class=spacer

Comment: That moved Everything down. I need the elements on the top to remain fixed in position.

Comment: It didn't look like that in the codepen update you made. Maybe you didn't save it? Either way, I went back to that technique (which I had tried this morning) and it worked now. I realized I forgot to close a <div>.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
.mainContent {
    background-color: #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: That made the content overlap. The fixed area must act as if it was the edge of the window. Content shouldn't under-lap or over-lap

Comment: Then I don't know what you want. You don't want to overlap or underlap your header but if it should act like a window edge it should underlap the header because this is how scrolling in a window works. Additionally you said in your question only that it should not underlap. So it is very confusing what exactly do you want.

Comment: It's alright @KittMedia. I do thank you for trying. Maybe underlapping is not a bad idea, if I mask it. But with what I have in mind, I'd rather I didn't have to use a big black square or even underlap. There are other ways. I just havent found it